# $.getJSON is not running inside addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have included the uncompressed version of jquery `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`. When I write $.getJSON function globally or in other user define functions and call that function globally it works fine but when I write $.getJSON function inside the addEventListener it give me this error `Uncaught TypeError: $.getJSON is not a function`.

```js
city.addEventListener("change", function(){
  cityName = this.value;
  $.getJSON('https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/' + cityName + '.json?access_token=' + API,
      function(data) {
          json = data;
      }
  );
  lng = json.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0];
  lat = json.features[0].geometry.coordinates[1];
  zoom = 10;
  mapfun();
});
```

and also when I define $.getJSON in user define the function and call that function in addEventListener it also gives me the same error.

```js
city.addEventListener("change", function(){
    cityName = this.value;
    getData();
    lng = json.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0];
    lat = json.features[0].geometry.coordinates[1];
    zoom = 10;
    mapfun();
});
function getData() {
    $.getJSON(url + cityName + '.json?access_token=' + API,
        function(data) {
            json = data;
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron

Comment: Why are you using "vanilla" `addEventListener` if you have jQuery?

Comment: Check your developer console, especially the network tab.  You should see the request.  `$.getJSON` *is* working, but it's asynchronous.  This means the rest of the code in your event listener runs while the `$.getJSON` is running in the background.  Once the request is done, at some point in the future, the callback will run.  You need to do everything relayed to the `data` (or `json`) variable inside the callback.

Comment: so how do I make asynchronous function synchronous?

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
 $(document).on('change', '#city', function() {
 var cityName=$("#city").val();

 // Your other stuff

 });
```

Comment: This doesn't address the asynchronous nature of `$.getJSON`.  Plus, why would you add a `change` event to **every** `input` element (assuming it's not a `select` element) when all we need is the `#city` (which may or not be the id) value?  I don't know why OP chose to use `city.addEventListener` instead of jQuery's event listeners, but that's not the problem here.

Comment: It does because it specifies .on which is needed for the function to work. Fair enough on the input, that can be changed easily to an id - done.

Comment: What do you mean by "`.on` [which] is needed for the function to work"?  jQuery's `.on()` just calls the native `.addEventListener()` internally.  The OP has correctly bound the `change` event to his `city` element.  The problem here is that `$.getJSON` is *asynchronous*.

Comment: .on is used to fire the function after the content has loaded! Without this actions fail on js generated content. Example: ever displayed content using AJAX and then wanted to make that content js interactive? Doesn't work unless you specify .on. I've tried it many times.

Comment: I see what you are saying.  What you are *actually* doing is binding an event to the `document` and just checking if the element triggered was `#city`.  This works because `document` always exists, whereas `#city` may not.  Generally, events are bound inside of a `$(function(){})` block (which is shorthand for `$(document).ready(function(){})`).  This makes sure the DOM elements exist before binding events.  When you add elements in the future - like from an AJAX callback - then you either need to bind the events *then* or have the event bound to a parent element (like `document`) that exists.

Comment: I'm assuming that `city` exists and was not added inside a callback.  So, the OP's code is fine in regard to event handling.  I assume this code is inside a `DOMContentLoaded` or `$(function(){})` block, so `city` should exist and you can bind to it.  You can also just do `$('#city').change(function(){})`.  You don't need to delegate events unless the element is added in the future.

Comment: See: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/